# How do I call my URL for json in Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid

Tags: xamarin, datagridview, json.net

I made a quick program to see if it works

Here is my Model

```
public class MistHeader
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    public string RecievedDate { get; set; }
    public string RequestNo { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string QuoteNo { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string Justification { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<MistHeader> MistHeader { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class ApprovalPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isRefreshing;

    public ObservableCollection<MistHeader> MistHeaders { get; set; }

    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get
        {
            return _isRefreshing;
        }
        set
        {
            _isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
        }
    }
    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; set; }

    public ApprovalPageViewModel()
    {
        MistHeaders = new ObservableCollection<MistHeader>();

        GetData();
        RefreshCommand = new Command(CmdRefresh);
    }

    private async void GetData()
    {
        string requestUrl = URL.MistHeaders;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
            try
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(content);
                    List<MistHeader> mistHeaders = root.MistHeader;

                    foreach (var item in mistHeaders)
                    {
                        MistHeaders.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void CmdRefresh()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

The code above returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Looks like my Binding is not correct. I did put in break points and what it looks like is that it bombs out at the foreach loop. Any Help would appreciated

Comment: are you just asking "how to load json from a url"?  There are hundreds of existing questions, posts, tutorials, etc on how to do that.

Comment: Into the xamarin.form.Datagrid I only get tutorials that has a json file embedded for the datagrid

Comment: 1) get the json data, 2) deserialize json into a C# model, 3) assign that model as the datasource for the grid.  It's difficult to provide a better answer without knowing what specific problem that you're having or what part of the process you don't understand how to do.

Comment: I've done everything without a model. Read somewhere else that i need to assign that model as the datasource for the grid. Thanks for your help much appreciated

Comment: use json2csharp.com to generate a model for your json.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.* There's nothing in the article you link to that loads JSON so we have no way of knowing what you tried, and where you went wrong.